# How does sauce lab will transfer the test results report from sauce lab to jenkins dashboard?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver, saucelabs

I am trying to use sauce labs with jenkins for the selenium functional test cases.

let's say I have a jenkins ci/cd pipeline in network-1 where it connects to git repo to checkout the code and do the deployment in network-2.

now after the deployment, selenium functional test cases has to run so jenkins is making connection to sauce labs

Once the tests are done executing on sauce labs and response is generated.

**how does sauce lab will transfer the test results report from sauce lab to jenkins dashboard ?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a two part answer.

The first part is, how does Sauce Labs know a test is successful?  When you're using Appium or Selenium, the answer is that *it doesn't*.  Selenium/Appium are only tools for driving a browser; Your test code has the final authority on whether a test passes or not.

To update the results on a Sauce Labs test, your test runner can use one of the methods listed here: https://docs.saucelabs.com/test-results/test-status/.

The second part is displaying results in Jenkins.  Since your test runner remains the authority here, you should focus on getting Jenkins to display the results from the test runner.  One thing you *can* do because of Sauce Labs is embed video results into the Jenkins test reports, using the [Sauce Labs Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sauce-ondemand/).  This does, however, rely on your tests generating a JUnit format XML result file.